# I can create spring-boot stater without spring.factories, why?

Tags: spring-boot

In the spring-boot guide [Creating your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html), It is mentioned that I have to create a META-INF/spring.factories file and put something under the EnableAutoConfiguration key. But I've created a starter without this file and it works well when a project is using it. Do you know why it works? Does it mean this file is optional?

Comment: Are you sure about this. For me it doesn't work without spring.factories

Comment: I suspect the configuration in your starter is being picked up by component scanning that's enabled in the project that's using it. What package is your starter's code in, and what packages are being component scanned by the project that's using it?

Comment: @pvpkiran As Andy said, you bean is probably bean loaded by a component scanning. Try to change the package to an weird name and see if the component is loaded.